# Having trouble finding a generator in Rails 3.1 for gem installed using git as source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activemessaging

First, I am using Rails 3.1.

I have installed the activemessaging gem from git.

This is in my Gemfile:

gem 'activemessaging', :git => 'git://github.com/kookster/activemessaging.git'

bundle show activemessaging outputs:

/Users/ken/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@cMoM/bundler/gems/activemessaging-037532e0eb69

and an ls of .../activemessaging-037532e0eb69 shows

a13g_test_harness filter processor tracer

Yet if I run one of the generators I get a generator not found message. Running rails g does not show any generators for activemessaging.

Does anyone know why these generators are not found?

Comment: Did you look at this? https://github.com/kookster/activemessaging/pull/9 looks like pull request that has not been added, maybe try that fork?